# Merge two separate arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have two arrays like below:

```
array
  'result1' => 
    array
      'entities' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(ElggUser)[979]
              ...
      'count' => int 1
array
  'result2' => 
    array
      'entities' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(ElggUser)[983]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(ElggUser)[986]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(ElggUser)[989]
              ...
          3 => 
            object(ElggUser)[992]
              ...
          4 => 
            object(ElggUser)[995]
              ...
          5 => 
            object(ElggUser)[998]
              ...
          6 => 
            object(ElggUser)[1001]
              ...
          7 => 
            object(ElggUser)[1004]
              ...
          8 => 
            object(ElggUser)[1007]
              ...
          9 => 
            object(ElggUser)[1010]
              ...
      'count' => int 1453
```

So I have tried array_merge for this like `array_merge($results1["result1"],$results2["result2"]);` but I am getting the 2nd array as result how do it? I am getting the result like:

```
array
      'entities' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(ElggUser)[983]
              protected 'attributes' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'url_override' => null
              protected 'icon_override' => null
              protected 'temp_metadata' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'temp_annotations' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'volatile' => 
                array
                  ...
              private 'valid' (ElggEntity) => boolean false
          1 => 
            object(ElggUser)[986]
              protected 'attributes' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'url_override' => null
              protected 'icon_override' => null
              protected 'temp_metadata' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'temp_annotations' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'volatile' => 
                array
                  ...
              private 'valid' (ElggEntity) => boolean false
          2 => 
            object(ElggUser)[989]
              protected 'attributes' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'url_override' => null
              protected 'icon_override' => null
              protected 'temp_metadata' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'temp_annotations' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'volatile' => 
                array
                  ...
              private 'valid' (ElggEntity) => boolean false
          3 => 
            object(ElggUser)[992]
              protected 'attributes' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'url_override' => null
              protected 'icon_override' => null
              protected 'temp_metadata' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'temp_annotations' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'volatile' => 
                array
                  ...
              private 'valid' (ElggEntity) => boolean false
          4 => 
            object(ElggUser)[995]
              protected 'attributes' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'url_override' => null
              protected 'icon_override' => null
              protected 'temp_metadata' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'temp_annotations' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'volatile' => 
                array
                  ...
              private 'valid' (ElggEntity) => boolean false
          5 => 
            object(ElggUser)[998]
              protected 'attributes' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'url_override' => null
              protected 'icon_override' => null
              protected 'temp_metadata' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'temp_annotations' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'volatile' => 
                array
                  ...
              private 'valid' (ElggEntity) => boolean false
          6 => 
            object(ElggUser)[1001]
              protected 'attributes' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'url_override' => null
              protected 'icon_override' => null
              protected 'temp_metadata' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'temp_annotations' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'volatile' => 
                array
                  ...
              private 'valid' (ElggEntity) => boolean false
          7 => 
            object(ElggUser)[1004]
              protected 'attributes' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'url_override' => null
              protected 'icon_override' => null
              protected 'temp_metadata' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'temp_annotations' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'volatile' => 
                array
                  ...
              private 'valid' (ElggEntity) => boolean false
          8 => 
            object(ElggUser)[1007]
              protected 'attributes' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'url_override' => null
              protected 'icon_override' => null
              protected 'temp_metadata' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'temp_annotations' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'volatile' => 
                array
                  ...
              private 'valid' (ElggEntity) => boolean false
          9 => 
            object(ElggUser)[1010]
              protected 'attributes' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'url_override' => null
              protected 'icon_override' => null
              protected 'temp_metadata' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'temp_annotations' => 
                array
                  ...
              protected 'volatile' => 
                array
                  ...
              private 'valid' (ElggEntity) => boolean false
      'count' => int 1453
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a multidimensional array, so use `array_merge_recursive`:

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($results1["result1"], $results2["result2"]);
```

for example:

```
$result1 = array("result1" => array("entities" => array(1, 2, 3)));
$result2 = array("result2" => array("entities" => array(4, 5, 6)));

var_dump(array_merge($result1["result1"], $result2["result2"]));
```

gives you

```
array(1) {
  'entities' =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    int(4)
    [1] =>
    int(5)
    [2] =>
    int(6)
  }
}
```

while

```
var_dump(array_merge_recursive($result1["result1"], $result2["result2"]));
```

gives you the expected

```
array(1) {
  'entities' =>
  array(6) {
    [0] =>
    int(1)
    [1] =>
    int(2)
    [2] =>
    int(3)
    [3] =>
    int(4)
    [4] =>
    int(5)
    [5] =>
    int(6)
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay i solved it in another way. I taken result1["entities"] & result2["entities"] then i got the values as i want.